# What C compilers are commonly used for embedded development on x86/x64 platforms?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded, intel

What C compilers are commonly used for embedded development on x86/x64 platforms?

Is GCC commonly used?

Comment: Well, if you omit the "C" word from the question, the votes would accumulate even faster...

Comment: By "development on x86/x64 platforms" do you mean that the target device will have an x86/x64 processor? The answers so far don't seem to think so, so you might want to make that clear...

Answer (score 3):

As already said, it depends on the architecture of the embedded system. However, more often than not, I have found a "ported" gcc cross-compiler for the architecture under question. Another popular compiler is [Keil](http://www.keil.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the architecture.

If you have an exotic architecture, let's say a standard model CPU customized by third-party (e.g. a modified MIPS, like Allegrex on PSP) then probably a standard GCC will not output the most optimized code. You would have to use their own tools/compilers (or modify GCC itself to add the modifications for this architecture).

If it's a standard architecture/CPU supported by GCC, then GCC should be as good, if not better, as any other C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on embedded systems(mainly DSP processors). I normally use just GCC for testing and simulating my initial code on a LINUX machine. But to create a code-set that would actually work on DSP, I have to use a separate compiler (VisualDSP++, it is developed by ADI for its own set of DSP processors). You might need to check with the manufacturer of the embedded system, which specific compiler to use.

Anshu

Answer (score 0):

Free software (GNU):  GCC, definitely.

Proprietary software for ARM might be Keil or IAR C compilers. IAR also supports a lot of other processors and simpler microcontrollers.